# like and where in codeigniter active record query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

i've this piece of code which should return the students details who belongs to particular school, i'm pasting the code

```
function return_student($query,$student_school){
    $this->db->select('student_name,student_subject,student_age,student_id');
    $this->db->from('students');
    $this->db->like('student_name',$query);
    $this->db->or_like('student_subject',$query);
    $this->db->where('student_school',$student_school);
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

now this piece of code is returning all data but not check whether that student belongs to that particular school or not, i don't know what i'm doing wrong!!!

Answer (score 0):

i got it,

```
$this->db->having('student_school',$student_school);
```